# finding an angle without any segment lengths

Tags: geometry

Said best with a picture. **Given angles a and b, solve for angle x.** (*Note that the top right vertex is also the center of the circle*)

[image: solve for X]

### What I've tried

Unable to find a simple method to get to x, I decided to draw all chords, and extend all segments to the edges of the triangle:

[image: added chords and extended lines]

I've managed to get just about every angle except the few I need to find x, so I'm not sure if this method of extending all lines has helped. Here's how far I got (excuse the rearrangement, I needed room to write):

[image: everything but what I need]

I think I'm overlooking something simple here. I'm not asking for the solution necessarily, just how I should get there.

*Also if someone could help me with a more technically descriptive title, I would love an edit.*

Comment: What is a? It's created by a bisector?

Comment: Not necessarily. It's just a known initial value.

Comment: Some info to check solutions against (possibly obvious to all already): If A is 0 then x must be 0.  If A is (90-B), x = B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scale the figure such that the circle is the unit circle.

[image]

Put a coordinate system such that $A$ is the center, and $C$ is on the $x$-axis

Now the point $D$ has coordinate

$$D=(\cos a,\,\sin a)$$

The sine of $b$ is $\frac{|AB|}{|AC|}$ so

$$\sin b=\frac1{|AC|}\implies|AC|=\csc b$$

Comparing $C$ and $D$ we find

$$\Delta x=\csc b-\cos a\qquad\qquad\Delta y=\sin a$$

Taking the arctangent of the slope of that, we get the angle

$$
\begin{align}
x&=\arctan\frac{\sin a}{\csc b-\cos a}\\
&=\arctan\frac{\sin a\sin b}{1-\sin b\cos a}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: For the uninformed: $$\csc x = \frac1{\sin x}$$

Comment: +1. You can tighten the argument slightly by avoiding coordinates, while taking advantage of your horizontal hypotenuse. I also might not scale, but would take $|AC|$ as my fundamental length. Then: Drop a perpendicular from $D$ to $F$ on $AC$. Since $|AD| = |AB| = |AC|\sin b$, we have 
$$|DF| = |AD|\sin a= |AC|\sin a\sin b \qquad\text{and}\qquad |AF| = |AD|\cos a = |AC|\sin a\cos a$$ Then, $$\tan x = \frac{|DF|}{|CF|} = \frac{|AC|\sin a\sin b}{|AC|-|AF|} = \frac{|AC|\sin a\sin b}{|AC|(1-\sin a\cos a)} = \frac{\sin a\sin b}{1 - \sin a \cos a}$$ This also avoids having to "explain" $\csc$. ;)

Comment: @Blue yeah, about csc, I have simplified it away now.

Comment: @Blue also your formula is slightly wrong, you said $$|AD|\sin a=|AC|\sin a\sin b$$ and then $$|AD|\cos a=|AC|\sin a\cos a$$ where the last should be $$|AD|\cos a=|AC|\sin b\cos a$$

Comment: Ah, I should be more careful TeXing in comments, since there's a time limit on fixing typos. Oh, well ...